# Getting "No such design unit" from Vivado

Tags: syntax-error, vhdl, hdl, vivado

I need someone to check my code and give me a sanity check. This is written in VHDL. Vivado keeps complaining the error:

> [Synth 8-493] no such design unit 'onesevenseg'

But, I can clearly see the file in my project and the project manager source window is listing the files in the proper way.

This is the line where the error occurs.

```
digitOne: entity xil_defaultlib.oneSevenSeg port map (switchIn, sevenSegOut);
```

Here is the top level file that has the error. It is compiled into the library `xil_defaultlib`.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity oneSevenSegTop is
    Port ( anodeOut : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 to 7);
           switchIn : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 to 3);
           sevenSegOut : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 to 6));
end oneSevenSegTop;

architecture Behavioral of oneSevenSegTop is
component oneSevenSeg 
    Port ( digitIn : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 to 3);
           segOut : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 to 6));
end component;
begin

digitOne: entity xil_defaultlib.oneSevenSeg port map (switchIn, sevenSegOut);

anodeOut <= "00000001";

end Behavioral;
```

Here is the file that is being instantiated by the above file, also compiled into the library `xil_defaultlib`.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity oneSevenSeg is
    Port ( digitIn : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 to 3);
           segOut : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 to 6));
end oneSevenSeg;

architecture Behavioral of oneSevenSeg is

begin
process(digitIn)
begin
if digitIn = "0000" then --0
    segOut <= "1000000";
elsif digitIn = "0001" then --1
    segOut <= "1111001";
elsif digitIn = "0010" then --2
    segOut <= "0100100";
elsif digitIn = "0011" then --3
    segOut <= "0110000";
elsif digitIn = "0100" then --4
    segOut <= "0011001";
elsif digitIn = "0101" then --5
    segOut <= "0010010";
elsif digitIn = "0110" then --6
    segOut <= "0000010";
elsif digitIn = "0111" then --7
    segOut <= "1111000";
elsif digitIn = "1000" then --8
    segOut <= "0000000";
elsif digitIn = "1001" then --9
    segOut <= "0011000";
else                   -- error
    segOut <= "0110110";
end if;

end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: The removed answer had your comment showing you had analyzed oneSevenSeg into library xil_defaultlib. It'd be helpful if that information was provided in your question as well as the actual error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying your two files with ghdl:

> % ghdl -a --work=xil_defaultlib onesevenseg.vhdl
>   % ghdl -a -P. onesevensegtop.vhdl
>   onesevensegtop.vhdl:17:18: no declaration for "xil_defaultlib"
>   ghdl: compilation error

So the second listed design unit from the question analyzed fine into a new working library named xil_defaultlib.

The second analysis is for the top level unit and the -P flag tells it to look in the current location for additional libraries.

And that analysis failed, because the name xil_defaultlib hasn't been declared.

IEEE Std 1076-2008, 13.2 Design libraries:

> A library clause defines logical names for design libraries in the host environment. A library clause appears as part of a context clause, either at the beginning of a design unit or within a context declaration.
>   ...
>   Each logical name defined by the library clause denotes a design library in the host environment.

Without telling the analyzer that the simple name `xil_defaultlib` references a library in the host environment the meaning of the name is unknown.

If the prefix isn't a library logical name then it must be a design unit, but the name isn't known in library work, library IEEE or library std:

12.3 Visibility:

> Visibility is either by selection or direct. A declaration is visible by selection at places that are defined as follows:
>
> > a) For a primary unit contained in a library: at the place of the suffix in a selected name whose prefix denotes the library.

Further in 13.2:

> Every design unit except a context declaration and package STANDARD is assumed to contain the following implicit context items as part of its context clause:
>
> **library** STD, WORK; **use** STD.STANDARD.**all**;

Notice library logical names can be defined implicitly as well as explicitly. There is no implicit definition for `xil_defaultlib`.

Add a library clause making the prefix of the selected name `xil_defaultlib.oneSevenSeg` visible.

This can be done right up there with the library clause making the library logical name `IEEE` visible in the unnamed top level file:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
library xil_defaultlib;

entity oneSevenSegTop is
...
```

So we make that change and:

> % ghdl -a -P. onesevensegtop.vhdl
>   %

No errors.

Comment: I didn't notice the missing `Library` clause ... think you have nailed it.

Comment: It was specifically the library clause.

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer from @user1155120 is correct, the underlying problem here is that you're not referencing the entity in the intended way. The `xil_defaultlib` is the name of the library that Xilinx Vivado compiles your design into by default. You do not need to reference this at all, instead, make use of the idea that `work` is used to refer to the library currently being compiled:

```
digitOne: entity work.oneSevenSeg port map (switchIn, sevenSegOut);
```

In this way, your code is not tied to the specific way that Vivado decides to compile your project. It doesn't make sense to add references to `xil_defaultlib` throughout your code when you could more easily use the `work` method.

Comment: You're missing a byplay addressing the same subject in comments to an answer that's been deleted.  There can be valid reasons for placing design units in separate libraries separate from the current working library.  Not 'the intended way', intended by whom?

Comment: @user1155120 Oh sorry, I don't know how to see deleted answers. It is not 'the intended way' to use the system, because the idea is not that every directly instantiated entity in a single-library design being created using Vivado references `xil_defaultlib`. Yes, you *can* work like this, but I get the feeling that based on your answer, the Asker is now going to be referencing `xil_defaultlib` everywhere, which is highly nonstandard, not to mention vendor dependent. I of course agree that there are plenty of cases where it is a good idea to use multiple libraries.